# Easiest & most efficient way to embed vimeo code into blog post

Tags: 7, panels, nodes

All of my videos are hosted on Vimeo and I would like to create a way to embed videos into my blog posts.

Ideally I'd like to create a field in my content type where all I have to do is input the Vimeo video ID and then the embed code is wrapped around it. This way I don't have to always paste the entire iframe. Or is there a better way?

For example if my Vimeo embed URL is the following, I'd like to only have to input the ID of "60771416"

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/60771416?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff9933" width="896" height="504" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

I guess I could have a field and have the embed code be in there by default, but I'd like to have it be cleaner then that.

I'm using Drupal 7 and Panels.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/vimeo_link_formatter

Comment: Hello :) "Easiest" is a pretty bad word - what's easy for one, may be difficult for another. Could you ask this in an less opinionated way?

Comment: Good point Molot. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Video Embed Field](https://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) is exactly what you are looking for.

To use:

1. Install the module and configure your video player at: /admin/config/media/vef_video_styles/list/normal/edit
2. Add a video url field to your content type

Test by adding a url to a piece of content in the video url field. Ex: http://vimeo.com/30403839

When you view the content, you should see the Vimeo video.

Video Embed Field is a very simple, straightforward module that works very well.

[Emfield](https://drupal.org/project/emfield) was great in D6, but in my experience has been less stable in D7.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a field to input just 60771416 instead of the whole iFrame. Then use the [theme_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) to wrap with iFrame and set attributes accordingly. Gives me more flexibility for the output. As well as its modular. The Google Analytic module do similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal Embedded field [module](https://drupal.org/project/emfield) and Vimeo media [module](https://drupal.org/project/media_vimeo) does exactly what you need out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

So far the answers I've seen depend on you having to add a field just for a Vimeo video. If you don't want to add a field and just want to embed them in the body, use the [Video Filter](http://dgo.to/video_filter) module.

With Video Filter, you just enable the option for your text format filter (like Full HTML, etc) and then you can add a video using a tag that looks like `[video:url]`. If you use a WYSIWYG like CKEditor, it also provides a button you can use that makes it even easier.